# Is there a method in Power Automate to multiply values between two columns in a SharePoint list and store the result in another list?

Tags: office365, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I have set up two lists in SharePoint. The first list is collecting data through a Microsoft Form, and it includes two columns that receive integer values. My objective is to automate the process of multiplying the values from these two columns and storing the result in a second list. How can I achieve this automation using Power Automate?

I have successfully created a Microsoft Form and connected it to my SharePoint list using Power Automate. The form is effectively receiving data and storing it in the list. However, I'm facing a challenge in automating the process of multiplying values from two columns and storing the result in a second list. I'd appreciate guidance on how to overcome this obstacle.

Comment: Created a calculated column for a start. That’s easier than anything. You could do that in both lists.

Comment: … also, *mul* is the expression for multiplication if you’re interested.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit because I am new in these things!

Comment: Create a calculated column so you not need to do the multiplication. Just Google it.